# The area bounded by the curve $x=a(\cos t)^3$ and $y=a(\sin t)^3$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Options are $a) \frac{3\pi a^2}{8}$    $b) \frac{3\pi a^2}{16}$  $a) \frac{3\pi a^2}{32}$   $a) 3\pi a^2$

I don't know how to approach this question. At first I tried to calculate area underneath the curve
$$\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+\left(\frac{y}{a}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}=1$$
(which is the curve I get on solving the 2 equations) and the 2 axes but I  couldn't solve the integral. tl;dr I don't understand the question

Comment: yeah sorry it was a mistake I fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that the area bounded by $y=f(x),$ $x$ axis and line $x=a$ to $x=b$ as $\displaystyle \int^b_a ydx$

Here we have $x=a\cos^3(t),y=a\sin^3(t)$

When we eliminate $t,$ we get

$$\displaystyle \bigg(x^2\bigg)^{\frac{1}{3}}+\bigg(y^2\bigg)^{\frac{1}{3}}=a^{\frac{2}{3}}$$

Which cut $x$ axis at $(\pm a,0)$ and $y$ axis at $(0,\pm a)$

Which is symmetrical about both quadrants.

So we will find area in $(1)$ st quadrant and multiply it by $4$

So the required area is $$\displaystyle A=4\int^a_0 ydx$$

$$\displaystyle =-4\int^0_{\frac{\pi}{2}}a\sin^3(t)\bigg(3a\cos^2(t)\sin(t)\bigg)dt$$

$$\displaystyle A=4\times 3a^2\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0\sin^4(t)\cos^2(t)dt$$

$$\displaystyle A=4\times 3a^2\bigg[\frac{(3\cdot 1)\cdot (1)}{6\cdot 4\cdot 2}\times \frac{\pi}{2}\bigg]=\frac{3\pi}{8}a^2$$

(Above for solving integral, we have used Wallis' formula)

Comment: Walli's fomrula?  The man's name was John Wallis.